# VS C# write a Console Output into a file

Tags: c#

I'm a beginner and looking for a solution. Need Help to Write this Code result from Console into the file. Please help. I tried all, but I did not find a good way to solve it.

```
     namespace ESA2Out {
         class Program {
             static string ESA2In(string verzeichnis, string dateiname, int zeilenlaenge = 0) {
                 string inhalt = string.Empty;
                 string dn = Path.Combine(verzeichnis, dateiname);
                 if (File.Exists(dn)) {
                     // Arrays einlesen
                     using(StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(dn)) {
                         inhalt = sr.ReadToEnd();
                         if (zeilenlaenge > 0) {
                             int anzahl = inhalt.Length / zeilenlaenge;
                             anzahl += inhalt.Length % zeilenlaenge > 0 ? 1 : 0;
                             string[] zeilen = new string[anzahl];
                             // Textzeilen extrahieren
                             for (int i = 0; i < anzahl; i++) {
                                 zeilen[i] = inhalt.Substring(i * zeilenlaenge, zeilenlaenge);
                             }
                             inhalt = string.Join("\r\n", zeilen);
                         }
                     }
                 } else {}
                 return inhalt;
             }

             static void ESA2Out(byte[] data, string verzeichnis, string dateiname) {
                 string dn = Path.Combine(verzeichnis, dateiname);
                 if (!File.Exists(dn)) {
                     using(FileStream fs = File.Create(dn)) {
                         fs.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                     }
                 } else {}
             }

             static void Main(string[] args) {
                 byte[] array = { 32, 32, 67, 67, 32, 32, 32, 35, 32, 35, 32, 32, 67, 32, 32, 67, 32, 32, 35, 32, 35, 32, 67, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 67, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 35, 32, 35, 32, 67, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 32, 67, 32, 32, 67, 32, 32, 35, 32, 35, 32, 32, 32, 67, 67, 32, 32, 32, 35, 32, 35, 32
                 };
                 ESA2Out(array, @ ".\\", "ESA2.txt");
                 Console.WriteLine();
                 Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                 Console.WriteLine(ESA2In(@ ".\\", "ESA2.txt", 11));
                 Console.ResetColor();
                 Console.ReadKey();
             }
         }
     }
```

That is the Code, it runs exactly, but now I don't find a way to write the result into the file. If I will open that file in Editor it should show the same as in the Console before.

Comment: Run your executable like `myapp.exe > thefile.txt`. This redirects the output into a file.

Comment: The text is `"  CC   # #  C  C  # # C     #####C      # # C     ##### C  C  # #   CC   # # "` and it will form a C# logo. Any particular reason that you implement it in this complex way?

Comment: I learn C# that is a task in a Book with no solution. It is the result from what I've learned in this Chapter.

Comment: Is there another way? I'm open to learn more :-)

Comment: I was thinking of `var s = "  CC   # #  C  C  # # C     #####C      # # C     ##### C  C  # #   CC   # # ";
for (int i=0; i<s.Length; i+=11)
Console.WriteLine(s.Substring(i,11));` - but yeah, it depends on what the book has explained so far and what it's trying to teach you.

Comment: I think it shut be programmed like this:

Comment: I think it shut be programmed like this:
Read file ESA2.txt write Console to Esa2.txt but I dont know how

Comment: I still don't fully get it, but how about `File.WriteAllText(".\\ESA2.txt", ESA2In(@".\\", "ESA2.txt", 11))` as the last line?

Comment: Wow so simple? Im amazed...that is it...thank you very much....

Comment: I wondered because File Write was a part in the chapter and im sure...my C# ist in the textfile

Comment: Hi Thomas Weller can I aske you something else....in German?

Comment: That's ok for me.

Comment: @Thomas Weller ich habe noch ein Verständisproblem in einer für mich komplexen Programmieraufgabe. Wie stelle ich Überlegungen an wo was genau gecodet werden muss. Das Programmieren ist mir relativ einfach gefallen, aber genau diese Fragen sind es die mir den Angstschweiß auf die Stirn treiben, weil das in den Büchern nicht so richtig rüberkam. wie zum Beispiel: a) Wo deklarieren Sie das Writer-Objekt, damit es an den Stellen im Programm, an denen es benötigt wird, auch bekannt ist? b) An welcher Stelle im Programm bauen Sie den Dateipfad zusammen, erstellen den Writer und schreiben den Header

Comment: @Thomas Weller - gibt es da eine Formel oder eine gewisse Vorgehensweise?

Comment: Das sind berechtigte und gute Fragen, sie aber gar nicht leicht zu beantworten sind. C# fällt am ehesten in die Kategorie der objektorientierten Sprachen. Dafür gibt es Prinzipien und Regeln. Das Standardwerk ist "Clean Code" von Robert C. Martin. Ich bin Trainer und bringe genau solche Themen unseren Entwicklern bei. Was bei R.C.Martin plausibel klingt und einleuchtet, ist es in der Praxis leider nicht. Da gibt es viel Ermessensspielraum und der lässt sich am besten aus Erfahrung heraus beurteilen.

Comment: Zu den von Ihnen konkret genannten Fragen sind die Prinzipien SRP (Single Responsibility Principle) und OCP (Open Closed Principle) vermutlich die beiden vorrangigen. Als nächstes kommen Sie vermutlich an ISP (Interface Segregation Principle) und DIP (Dependency Inversion Principle) nicht vorbei. Ich habe außerdem gute Erfahrungen damit gemacht, Unit Tests zu schreiben - und zwar egal ob vorher (TDD) oder nachher. In Unit Tests möchten Sie **nie** in eine Datei schreiben. Allein diese Erkenntnis bzw. Entscheidung wird Ihren Code wesentlich verändern (und tatsächlich verbessern)

Comment: also wäre die Buchempfehlung an der Stelle Clean Code ? ich habe schon soviele Bücher verschlungen, und dazu nirgendswo was gefunden....

Comment: Das ist tatsächlich ein Problem: ich kenne noch kein besseres Buch, nicht mal sein Nachfolgerbuch Clean Architecture. Das Buch "Clean Code" ist nicht falsch, nur vielleicht etwas einseitig und betrachtet die Gegenseite oder Ausnahmen zu wenig. Als Clean Code Evangelist muss er das vielleicht so machen, wer weiß...